# Postgressql cant access from outside

Tags: postgresql

I am able to access postgres from the server where I have installed it. Not from different server.

Netstat output:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

my config file

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

What could be the reason I am not able to access this from outside the server?

Error:

```
Is the server running on host "" (IP) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to connect? Best guess is there a firewall blocking port 5432.  Two things 1) You probably should make the comments match the record line e.g. 0.0.0.0/0 is not local connections. 2) You have not set up remote connection for IPv6.

Comment: Added the error..

Comment: That confirms my best guess. You have a firewall blocking port 5432.

Comment: If you do open the firewall and the server is publicly accessible you would want to tighten up the access rules in `pg_hba.conf`. Currently you are allowing connections from any host to any database as any user, that is not a good idea.